# Pandas how to keep sheets untouched

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel workbook that has more than one worksheets (i.e. sheet1 and sheet2)
and i did like this:

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
####doing something on shee1, sheet2 is not touched######
df1.to_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
```

By doing above, I found sheet2 missing after saving the file.

Is there a way to open and save on same file without affecting other worksheets?

Comment: You should provide more details. When you edit an Excel file then **all** worksheets must be loaded and then saved.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way to do that is by loading all of your sheets, then modifying only the first one. Although it works, you may loose any custom styling from your tables.

```py
# Load all sheets
workbook = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

# do something to workbook['sheet1']

# Write all sheets to excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for sheet, df in workbook.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
writer.save()
```

---

As far as I know, the only way to overwrite a sheet ─ while keeping the other ones untouched ─ requires using third-party libraries. For instance,
here's an option with [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

First, modify the data as you wish:

```py
import pandas as pd

fname = 'file.xlsx'
target_sheet = 'sheet1'

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
# further modification to `df` ...
```

then, save it to the specified sheet:

```py
# Load required functions
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

# Read excel file (all sheets)
wb = load_workbook(fname)

# Get the index from target-sheet
idx = wb.sheetnames.index(target_sheet)

# Delete the existing target-sheet
del wb[target_sheet]

# Create a new empty target-sheet
wb.create_sheet(target_sheet, idx)

# Write `df` data on it
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    wb[target_sheet].append(r)
    
# Save file
wb.save(fname)
```

Comment: thanks. sheet_name=None does help. However i have 1 more question. for workbook['sheet1']. If i assign a name to it, i.e. df=workbook['sheet1']. when i run the for loop it does not seem to work. is there a way to give this sheet a name? because in the code i'm using it like 100 times..just do not want to repeat workbook['sheet1'] 100 times. using df would be much easier

Comment: Hi @CCCCos! I'm sorry, but I didn't understand your question. The code `df=workbook['sheet1']` does work, right!? So it may be something related to your loop. What is your loop for? I mean, what it's doing? The sheet name here is 'sheet1', but it can be whatever name your sheet has. Do you want to change the sheet name?

Comment: Hi @Cainã Max Couto-Silva.So below is my code:
workbook = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df_sheet1 = workbook['sheet1']
###do something with df_sheet1###
for sheet, df in workbook.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)

Above only updated df_sheet1, however in the for loop, the actual workbook['sheet1'] was not updated. so when i check the file, it appears nothing is updated

Comment: So the thing here is that you've read your data to `df_sheet1` and it's trying to save it as `df.to_excel`. It's not gonna work, you should either do read as `df` or saving as `df_sheet1.to_excel`. Once `df` is only temporarily (I suppose), I'd recommend to read as `df` instead of `df_sheet1`. If you want to set a name to dataframe, you can use a dictionary, but I don't think it's worth it. It depends on your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something is going on in the below section that is throwing off the code:

####doing something on ws1, ws2 is not touched######

When I ran your code on my system the workbook still returned both worksheets
As an isolation test can you comment/remove the code in that section and confirm if the error still appears.

Comment: I found the issue was actually caused by Pandas..so the actual question would be: how to keep other sheets with Pandas.